# How to create an inequality constraint on the inner product of two columns in CVXPY?

Tags: python, python-2.7, mathematical-optimization, convex-optimization, cvxpy

Suppose my constraint is the product of the first column and third column of the matrix variable is greater than one. How can I implement in CVXPY? Example:

```
w = Variable(4,3)
```

In Matlab, my constraint would be:

```
w(:,1)'*w(:,3)>1
```

How can I implement it in CVXPY? Or can we perform dot product under CVXPY? `numpy.dot` is not supported by CVXPY.

Answer (score 4):

If both variables are positive then the set `{x * y > 1}` is actually convex, while the function `x*y` is neither convex nor concave. This can be  checked by looking at eigenvalues of matrix of second derivatives

```
(x*y)'' = 
[[0, 1],
 [1, 0]]
```

which are `{-1, 1}`. The matrix is not positive-definite and is not negative-definite.

Sometimes you can transform a problem so that it becomes convex. In this case this is possible by taking a logarithm of both sides:

```
log(x) + log(y) >= 0
```

this is a valid restriction because both log(x) and log(y) are concave functions and the inequality is greater-than-or-equal. This constraint will pass the "disciplined convex programming" rules. Good luck.

Comment: wait a minute. $x$ and $y$ here are vectors. what do you mean by the log of a vector?

Comment: @Apprentice in my example, x and y are not vectors. Looking back, my answer should have been a comment because it does not really solve the problem. Furthermore, I am not sure that the set described in the question is a convex set

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to multiply two Variables, all constraints have to be linear (in general [DCP](https://cvxpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/dcp/index.html)).

CVXPY raise DCPError if you try to do a forbidden operation.

```
import cvxpy
x = cvxpy.Variable()
y = cvxpy.Variable()
constraints = [x*y > 1]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cvxpy\expressions\expression.py", line 43, in cast_op
    return binary_op(self, other)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cvxpy\expressions\expression.py", line 226, in __mul__
    raise DCPError("Cannot multiply two non-constants.")
cvxpy.error.DCPError: Cannot multiply two non-constants.
```

You can use slack variable to avoid this if at least one variable is integer/boolean. Otherwise you can use any nonlinear solver e.g. IPOPT.

The same question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22345756/2810747).

Answer (score 0):

You have a strict inequality constraint on the northeast entry of the Gram matrix `Q := W.T * W`, which is symmetric and positive semidefinite. Hence, do work with Gram matrix `Q` instead and then introduce the strict inequality constraint `Q[0,2] > 1`.

For example, here's a **semidefinite program** (SDP) with zero objective:

```
>>> from cvxpy import *
>>> Q = Semidef(3)
>>> objective = Minimize(0)
>>> constraints = [ Q[0,2] > 1 ]
>>> prob = Problem(objective,constraints)
>>> prob.solve()
0.0
>>> Q.value
matrix([[  2.33101529e+00,   2.57980002e-30,   1.76709537e+00],
        [  2.57980002e-30,   2.57740598e-15,  -2.00304682e-30],
        [  1.76709537e+00,  -2.00304682e-30,   2.33101529e+00]])
```

Note that the northeast entry is `1.76709537e+00 > 1`. To recover matrix `W` from Gram matrix `Q`, use the Cholesky decomposition and append a row of zeros to obtain a 4 x 3 matrix, as follows:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> L = np.linalg.cholesky(Q.value)
>>> W = (np.insert(L, 3, np.array([0,0,0]), axis=1)).T
>>> W
matrix([[  1.52676628e+00,   1.68971508e-30,   1.15741053e+00],
        [  0.00000000e+00,   5.07681591e-08,  -7.79768444e-23],
        [  0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   9.95698832e-01],
        [  0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00]])
```

Let us verify:

```
>>> W.T * W - Q.value
matrix([[  0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00],
        [  0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   7.00649232e-46],
        [  0.00000000e+00,   7.00649232e-46,   0.00000000e+00]])
```